# Clarifying the difference between a set being an element of a set, and a set being a subset of another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

> Clarify the difference between a set being *an element* of a set, and a set being *a subset* of another set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For $S=\{\color{blue}{1}, \, \color{red}{\{1\}}\}$, the set $\color{red}{\{1\}}$ is an element of the set $S$ and the set $\{\color{blue}{1}\}$ is a subset of the set $S$.

Comment: This looks like an exam question. Therefore you need to provide the answer that you have been taught. In set theory the situation is clear: $a\in b$ is the *primitive* (postulated) relation (and it means "$a$ is element of $b$") whereas $a\subset b$ is *defined* as $(\forall x)(x\in a\implies x\in b)$. However, depending on how you have been taught set theory, this answer may be good, or too high level, or too terse etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set theory: difference between belong/contained and includes/subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131309/set-theory-difference-between-belong-contained-and-includes-subset)