# Is λ={λ} true or not

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I know that λ={λ} is true I want to know How can I prove that λ={λ} is true or not?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know this is true?

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are asking. Although it looks somewhat similar to this question from set theory: [When is $x=\{x\}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125385/when-is-x-x). But your question is tagged [tag:automata], so you have probably something completely different in mind.

Comment: In my reference book i read about it and the writer said its equal

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak: the lambda is empty set

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us what $\lambda$ is and the name of the book (and link, if the text is online)?

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak: no its not an online book. its an automata question

Comment: Are you sure $\lambda$ refers to the empty set, and not the null string? Of course, even if it does refer to the null string, I can't guess that they mean by the equation. (e.g. what is $\{ \lambda \}$?)

Comment: @emma: Martin asked for the _name_ of the book, not whether it was online or not.

Answer (score 4):

Martin is right, assuming his interpretation of the question.

However, it looks more likely to me that you've encountered a common abuse of notation in formal language theory, in which **any word can be used as a shorthand for the language containing that word and nothing else**.

This is convenient -- but potentially confusing -- because among other things it allows *regular expressions* to be written fairly succinctly.
For example $ab^*cb$ means the language $\{acb,abcb,abbcb,abbbbcb,\ldots\}$. Without this convention we'd need to be write the regular expression as $\{a\}\{b\}^*\{cb\}$, wasting ink and attention on brackets that don't really add useful meaning in most contexts.

Your $\lambda=\{\lambda\}$ is then just this convention in the special case where the word is the empty word. It doesn't really say that $\lambda$ *is* its own singleton set; just that we're traditionally allowed to write $\lambda$ where we really mean $\{\lambda\}$. The onus is then on the reader to figure out that must be what we meant because $\{\lambda\}$ makes better sense than $\lambda$ in the context we use it in.

(Though, of course, the real onus is on the *writer* not to use such abbreviation in contexts where there is any doubt about their meaning).

Comment: +1 I think this is the relevant answer in this context, given the tags on the question.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321426/is-true-or-not/321432#comment695660_321426) that $\lambda$ is your notation for the [empty set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set). A more standard notation is $\emptyset$, so I will use this notation.

What you wrote is not true, $\emptyset\ne\{\emptyset\}$.

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if they contain the same elements, i.e., if
$$(\forall x)x\in A\Leftrightarrow x\in B.$$
This is called [extensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality).

This equivalence does not hold for $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\{\emptyset\}$. Just take $x=\emptyset$. You have $\emptyset\in B$ and $\emptyset\notin A$.

In other words, $\emptyset$ belongs to $\{\emptyset\}$, but it does not belong to $\emptyset$, therefore $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset$ must be different sets.

Comment: I dont understand yet!!

Comment: This question is very similar to yours (identical, if I understand your question correctly):
[Empty set does not belong to empty set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/empty-set-does-not-belong-to-empty-set)